# Inner-Join on temporary columns using MAX()

Tags: mysql, mariadb, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have the table t in MariaDB (latest), which includes among others the columns person_ID, date_1, date_2. They contain person IDs and string dates respectively. For each ID there is only one date_1, but multiple date_2. Rows either have a date_1 or date_2 that is why I am joining on ID. Here is an example of the table t:

| person_ID | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | - | 3 |
| A | - | 5 |
| A | 1 | - |
| B | - | 10 |
| B | - | 14 |
| B | 5 | - |
| C | - | 11 |
| C | - | 9 |
| C | 7 | - |

Create and fill table t:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
id SERIAL,
person_ID TEXT,
date_1 TEXT,
date_2 TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_2) VALUES ('A', 3);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_2) VALUES ('A', 5);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_1) VALUES ('A', 1);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_2) VALUES ('B', 10);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_2) VALUES ('B', 14);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_1) VALUES ('B', 5);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_2) VALUES ('C', 11);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_2) VALUES ('C', 9);
INSERT INTO t (person_ID, date_1) VALUES ('C', 7);

SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

The following is an inner-join of two subqueries A and B. Query A gives a distinct list of person_IDs, which contain a date_1, and date_1 itself. On the other hand query B should give a distinct list of person_IDs that contain a date_2, and MAX(date_2).

```
SELECT A.person_ID, A.date_A,  B.date_B, B.date_B - A.date_A AS diff FROM
    (SELECT person_ID, date_1 AS date_A FROM t
    WHERE date_1 >= 0) A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT person_ID, MAX(date_2) AS date_B FROM t
    WHERE date_2 >= 0
    GROUP BY person_ID) B
ON A.person_ID = B.person_ID
AND B.date_B > A.date_A
AND (B.date_B - A.date_A) <= 7
GROUP BY A.person_ID;
```

That gives the output:

| person ID | date_A | date_B | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5 | 4 |
| C | 7 | 9 | 2 |

But this would be the desired outcome (ignoring ID = B, because diff = 9):

| person ID | date_A | date_B | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5 | 4 |
| C | 7 | 11 | 4 |

I assume MAX(date_2) gives 9 instead of 11 for person_ID = C, because that value was inserted last for date_2.

You can use this [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQUzqvCUAhc7Bc5AKHHvZd/0#&togetherjs=joMJCJpBmP) to try it out yourself.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Comment: MySQL<>MariaDB. Which is it?

Comment: Seems likely your original query part A join B on id could just use t join B where <on condition from A>. Getting the greatest n per group is a faq & even a tag. If your maxs are wrong there's a common error pattern where people aggregate over the wrong tables and/or assemble aggregations wrongly.

Comment: Seems unlikely you want that A has multiple (duplicate) rows per id, which it does unless its where prevents them.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. "Please act on the comments." PS Poorly received questions (score < 1) count towards posting limits whether deleted or not. [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is made harder by your sparse table (rows with NULLs). Here's how I would approach this.

Start with a subquery to clean up the sparse table. It generates a result set where the rows with nulls are removed, generating a result like this.

```
person_ID     date_1    date_2   diff
        A        1        3        2
        A        1        5        4
        B        5       10        5
        B        5       14        9
        C        7       11        4
        C        7        9        2
```

This puts the single `date_1` value for each person into the rows with the `date_2` values.  The [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQUzqvCUAhc7Bc5AKHHvZd/2) to do that is:

```sql
 SELECT t.person_ID, b.date_1, t.date_2, t.date_2 - b.date_1 diff
   FROM t 
   JOIN t b      ON t.person_ID = b.person_ID
                AND b.date_1 IS NOT NULL
                AND t.date_2 IS NOT NULL
```

Let's name the output of that subquery with the alias `detail`.

Your business logic calls for the very common [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query pattern. It calls for retrieving the row with the largest `diff` for each `person_ID`, as long as `diff <= 7`. With that `detail` subquery we can write your logic a little more easily. In your result set you want the row for each `person_ID` that shows `date_1`, `date_2`, and `diff` for the largest diff, but leaving out any rows with a `diff` > 7.

First, write [another subquery](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQUzqvCUAhc7Bc5AKHHvZd/3) that finds the largest qualifying `diff` value for each `person_ID`.

```sql
SELECT person_ID, MAX(diff) diff
   FROM detail
  GROUP BY person_ID
 HAVING MAX(diff) <= 7
```

Then join that subquery to the detail to get your desired result set.

```sql
 SELECT detail.*
   FROM detail
   JOIN ( SELECT person_ID, MAX(diff) diff
            FROM detail
           GROUP BY person_ID
           HAVING MAX(diff) <= 7
        ) md ON detail.person_ID = md.person_ID 
             AND detail.diff = md.diff
```

Now, I used a [common table expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to write this query: to define the `detail`. That syntax is available in MariaDB 10.2+ (and MySQL 8+). Putting it together, here is the query.

```sql
 WITH detail AS
 (SELECT t.person_ID, b.date_1, t.date_2, t.date_2 - b.date_1 diff
        FROM t 
        JOIN t b ON t.person_ID = b.person_ID
                AND b.date_1 IS NOT NULL
                AND t.date_2 IS NOT NULL
 )
 SELECT detail.*
   FROM detail
   JOIN ( SELECT person_ID, MAX(diff) diff
            FROM detail
           GROUP BY person_ID
           HAVING MAX(diff) <= 7
        ) md ON detail.person_ID = md.person_ID 
             AND detail.diff = md.diff
```

Summary: the steps to solving your problem.

- Deal with the sparse-data problem in your input table ... get rid of the input rows with NULL values by filling in `date_1` values in the rows that have `date_2` values. And, throw in the `diff`s.
- Find the largest eligible `diff` values for each `person_ID`.
- Join that list of largest `diff`s back into the detail table to extract the correct row of the detail table.

**Pro tip**  Don't turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. You don't want to rely on MySQL / MariaDB's [strange nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html), because it sometimes yields the wrong values. When it does that it's baffling.